Can your friends/family go to your Dissertation Proposal? (not one's final defense, but the proposal)
I am presenting my dissertation proposal (first three chapters) to my committee in a week, and my friends/family asked if they could come. I know they can come for the final defense, but what about the dissertation proposal?
Thanks!

That would be a question for your adviser and/or graduate director. Surely it depends on your school.

You can ask locally, but this would have been very unusual in my graduate program.
The final defense in my program was a public presentation, but other committee meetings certainly were not. The dissertation proposal would have been part of one of those ordinary committee meetings.
Students separately also typically presented their proposal with preliminary findings in a seminar to the rest of the graduate program - that seminar was also not typically open to the public and I don't recall anyone's family attending a talk ever, but it might be possible without being too weird.
But, overall, I'd thank them for being supportive and tell them you're excited to have them attend your final defense when it's time! If they want an excuse to visit, you might come up with another alternative for something purely social.

Definitely ask locally! Where I went to grad school the thesis proposal was an open event that lots of other students and sometimes faculty went to. It wasn't uncommon for people outside the department to attend. But where I am now it's typically just the student+committee.
